# Attribute error while trying to use MDDropDownMenu widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu


class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
        caller=self.drop,
        callback=self.drop_down,
        width_mult=4,
        items=self.menu_items
    )

@staticmethod
def drop_down(instance):
    print(instance.text)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()



my.kv

<WindowManager>:
    MainWindow:


<MainWindow>:
    drop:drop
    Button:
        id: drop
        pos_hint : {'center_x': .5 , 'center_y':.5}
        on_release: root.menu.open()
```

I was trying to bind the button with the DropDown instantiated in the MainWindow class , it was working fine while i wasn't using a screen manager as the root but now it doesn't run properly.
This is the error appearing when i run the program.

***AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'drop'***

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because the `drop` attribute of `MainWindow` is not created until the `kv` rule is executed, which happens after the `__init__()` method is run. So you cannot use the `ids` in the `__init__()` method. One way to avoid that error is to delay accessing the `ids` by using `Clock.schedule_once()`. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu


class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup)

    def setup(self, *args):
        self.menu_items = [ {'text':'abba'}, {'text':'dabba'}, {'text':'doo'}]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
        caller=self.drop,
        callback=self.drop_down,
        width_mult=4,
        items=self.menu_items)

    @staticmethod
    def drop_down(instance):
        print(instance.text)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer this!! It works.

Comment: thanks "John Anderson" Clock is good method for detect errors for fix it , @Habesha click on this answer is useful